# Why is the entropy of a posterior Gaussian distribution higher than its prior?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am puzzled with a problem regarding the entropy of a multivariate Gaussian distribution after a Bayesian-like update.

Let $\mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \Sigma_0)$ be a prior $D$-dimensional multivariate Gaussian distribution. After conditioning this distribution on noisy observations, let the resulting posterior Gaussian distribution (of same dimensionality $D$) be $\mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \Sigma_1)$.

The entropy of each probability distribution is calculated with the following formula:

$$H=\frac{1}{2}ln|\Sigma|+\frac{D}{2}(1+\ln(2\pi))$$

My question: **Given that the posterior distribution is more confident (carries less uncertainty) than the prior distribution, why would its entropy increase?**

I put together a toy example with dimensionality $D=18$. Here are two covariance matrices (of shape 18x18). The prior covariance ($\Sigma_0$) is shown on the left and it is conditioned on some observations, resulting in the posterior covariance ($\Sigma_1$) on the right:

[image]

The magnitude of the values in the posterior covariance matrix are clearly lower than the values in the prior covariance matrix, and yet its entropy is higher (128 > 103). How is that possible? I would have expected the entropy to decrease since the posterior distribution is a lot less uncertain than the prior distribution.

My understanding of entropy here is probably flawed, any intuitive explanation/clarification would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example is not very clear, and I'm not sure if this is the case, but:

In general, (and, more simply, with discrete variables, and true Shannon entropies [*]), "conditioning reduces the entropy", that's true... but only in average.

That is: $H(X | Y) \le H(X)$ is true. But this does *not* imply $H(X | Y =y) \le H(X)$ for all $y$. The entropy conditioned on some particular value *can* increase.

For example, let $X, Y$ have this joint probability:

$$ 
\begin{array}{c|cc}
X \backslash   Y &  0 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0  \\
1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
\end{array}
$$

Then $H(Y | X=0)= 0 $ but $H(Y | X=1)= 1 $ , hence $H(Y | X=1) > H(Y)$

---

[*] Remember that differential entropy is not really the Shannon entropy, and not all the properties of the latter apply to the former. But this does not seem to be your problem.

Comment: Oh I think I understand, your example is helpful! The example in my question is essentially a Bayesian update (start with a prior distribution, and calculate the posterior distribution given a few noisy observations). For some reason, I was surprised to see that the entropy of the posterior was higher despite the fact that the posterior covariance matrix had smaller values. But as you pointed out, conditioning on some observations does not necessarily mean that the entropy will decrease. Thanks!

Comment: The only difference with your example is that you take the conditional distribution and go from a 2-D (bivariate) distribution to a 1-D distribution. In my example above, the Bayesian update does not change the dimensionality of the system. But I think the same logic applies.